# Setting up the EFI Shell in Qemu to allow for Http requests

Tags: http, qemu, uefi, edk2

I am developing an UEFI App that will need to perform a GET request through http.

As a start up point, I want to make sure my setup is working properly so that the http requests can actually go through.

To that end, I spent the last few days trying to make the `http` command work in the EFI Shell launched inside QEMU.
I can get the `ping` command to work properly, but calling:

```
http httpbin.org/get
```

Always returns:

```
 Unable to open http protocol on `eth0` - Unsupported
 Unable to download the file `/get` on `eth0` - Unsupported
```

This is my startup.nsh script to configure the EFI Shell's interface:

```
connect
ifconfig -r eth0
ifconfig -s eth0 dhcp
ifconfig -l eth0
```

These were my different attempts at invoking Qemu properly:

```
       -netdev user,id=mynet0,hostfwd=tcp::8080-:80 -device e1000,netdev=mynet0 \
        -netdev user,id=user.0 -device e1000,netdev=user.0 \
        -nic user,ipv6=off,model=e1000,mac=52:54:98:76:54:32 \
```

And following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/extremecoders-re/e8fd8a67a515fee0c873dcafc81d811c) I tried to setup a tap, albeit without luck, I'd launch qemu with the following configuration:

```
 -netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device e1000,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 \
```

Do you have any clue what step am I missing?

Where do you believe I could be failing in making `eth0` supported?

Is the tap crucial?

Are you able to make this setup work on your side?

Update:

Very good suggestion @MiSimon, I hadn't realized that the HttpDxe driver wasn't being built with the OvmfPkg.

I have now added its INF to `OvmfPkgX64.dsc` and `OvmfPkgX64.fdf`.

Although, running `drivers` is displaying a duplicate entry:

```
0000000A D - -  1  - HttpDxe                             HttpDxe
0000000A ? - -  -  - HttpDxe                             HttpDxe
```

With respect to calling the `http` command, the error has progressed to:

```
Downloading 'http://httpbin.org/get'
Unable to download the file '/get' on 'eth0' - Unsupported
```

The debug log shows:

```
HttpNotify: Event - 0, EventStatus - Unsupported
Error: Could not retrieve the host address from DNS server.
```

Comment: Is the HttpDxe driver loaded in qemu? You can use the 'drivers' command in the efi shell to list the loaded drivers.

Comment: Thank you @MiSimon! That seemed to be part of the issue. I have updated the question. Maybe now I'm missing the tap? I lack a proper mental model for this networking business

Comment: Is the DnsDxe driver loaded? You will need the SnpDxe, MnpDxe, ArpDxe, Dhcp4Dxe, Ip4Dxe, Udp4Dxe, TcpDxe, DnsDxe, HttpDxe and maybe the HttpUtilitiesDxe driver for this to work.

Comment: Hot damn! Those did the trick. Thank you! Would you kindly post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool requires nearly all network drivers to be loaded.

Make sure your image contains the following drivers:

- SnpDxe
- MnpDxe
- ArpDxe
- Ip4Dxe/Ip6Dxe
- Dhcp4Dxe/Dhcp6Dxe
- Udp4Dxe/Udp6Dxe
- DnsDxe
- TcpDxe
- HttpDxe
- HttpUtilitiesDxe

All of them are can be found in EDK2 inside the [NetworkPkg](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/edk2-stable202211/NetworkPkg).